# dependency loops in C

Tags: c, openmp

I need some hints how to avoid dependency in 3 loops.

I've tried openmp and openacc to see the compiler's messages, but I didn't manage to solve them.

```
for (int c = 0; c < oCr; c++) // 248, Loop carried reuse of mx-> prevents parallelization // #pragma acc loop seq
    for (int i = 0; i < sir[c]; i++) // 249, Loop carried dependence of mx-> prevents parallelization Loop carried backward dependence of mx-> prevents vectorization // #pragma acc loop seq
        for (int v = 1; v <= p; v++)  // 250, Loop is parallelizable // #pragma acc loop vector(128) /* threadIdx.x */
            if (flat2(vj3, p1, b2, b1, ls6j, v))
                mx[v - 1] = flat5(ct7, e4, e3, e2, e1, a5, a4, a3, a2, a1, ls6j, c, 5, v, SmM);

int k = 0;
for (int i = ma; i >= mi; i--) // 275, Loop carried reuse of ti-> prevents parallelization Loop carried scalar dependence for k at line 279,278 // 275, #pragma acc loop seq
    for (int c = 0; c < (p - nA); c++) // 276, Accelerator restriction: size of the GPU copy of ti,tm is unknown Loop carried reuse of ti-> prevents parallelization Loop carried scalar dependence for k at line 279,278 // 276, #pragma acc loop seq
        if ((tm[c]) == i) { // 277
            ti[k] = c; // 278
            k++; // 279
        }

for (int v = 1; v <= p; v++) // 287, omp Loop not vectorized: data dependency Generated 1 prefetches in scalar loop // 287 acc Loop carried reuse of px-> prevents parallelization 287, #pragma acc loop seq
    for (int s = 0; s < os; s++) // 288, omp Loop unrolled 4 times (completely unrolled) // acc 288, Accelerator restriction: size of the GPU copy of px is unknown Complex loop carried dependence of px-> prevents parallelization Loop carried reuse of px-> prevents parallelization 288, #pragma acc loop seq
        if (flat2(ve1, f1, l2, l1, ls6j, s) == ix[v - 1] + 1) {
            int xx;
            #pragma omp atomic capture
            xx = x++;
            flat2(px, os*ol, 0, 0, 0, xx) = v;
            flat2(px, os*ol, 0, 0, 1, xx) = ls6j;
        }
```

flat2 and flat5 are macros for indexes

```
#define flat2(m0, e1, a2, a1, i2, i1) m0[(i2-a2)*(e1-a1) + (i1-a1)]
#define flat5(m0, e4, e3, e2, e1, a5, a4, a3, a2, a1, i5, i4, i3, i2, i1) m0[(i5-a5)*(e4-a4)*(e3-a3)*(e2-a2)*(e1-a1) + (i4-a4)*(e3-a3)*(e2-a2)*(e1-a1) + (i3-a3)*(e2-a2)*(e1-a1) + (i2-a2)*(e1-a1) + (i1-a1)]
```

thank you

Comment: Why macros instead of a function?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < sir[c]; i++)` can't be parallelized it can potentially modify `mx[1]` when `i=0` and again when `i=1`. Parallelizing could affect the order you assign to `mx[1]`, thus it could affect the final result, thus it can't be allowed. Similar issues exist in the other loops.

Comment: "I've tried openmp and openacc to see the compiler's messages" Can you be more specific?

Comment: @purplepsycho, They're provided as comments.

Comment: @ikegami, OK, then for the first I will rewrite. I thought at least the second loop with "k problem" can be solved with a small trick. Third is completely over my understanding.

Comment: @tadman I just took the way from an old code and it works fine. I don't know the advantages of functions. For sure it will be slower(maybe difficult) for a function in openacc (needs inline, routine and so on)

Comment: Modern C compilers can inline if they think it's worth it. Macros are for old compilers that had no clue, but those are basically extinct.

Comment: Did you copy everything from an old code or just the two macros? If I'm correct the second one looks like a sorting algorithm where you do not actually sort the array `tm` but use `ti` to save the permutation which would lead to a sorted array `tm` - if all values of `tm` are between `mi` and `ma`. So just look up (parallelizable) sorting algorithms.

Comment: @Shadow yes, the second nested loop is a sorting alg which gives only the positions back, not the values. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Regarding the first lines: I don't see any use of `i`. And `c` is only used in the innermost line of code. As you just set the values of `mx` dependent on `v` you could delete the loop over `c` and the one over `i` and just set `c = oCr-1`.

Comment: @Shadow looking on parallelizable counting sort algirithm how you sugested, I realized that making k private (and automatically reduction + for k) solved the problem. I will check last sugestion now. Thank you. The third loop is still on the table